# Stealth Bomber won't fire on cities

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I upgraded my Bomber to a Stealth Bomber, and since then it was unable to attack any city.

The bomber could attack cities. But the stealth bomber just can't. When I went into attack mode of the stealth bomber, it doesn't display the option to attack cities within range. I even tried moving it to other cities and targeting other Civs' cities, but it doesn't work.

And yes, all the cities I was targeting, they belonged to Civs I was at war with.

When I had Gods And Kings, my stealth bombers could still attack cities. This bug has started since I upgraded to BNW.

EDIT: In the question that is linked to this question, with this question marked as a duplicate, it says that the Stealth Bomber fired on the turn before. In my case, it can always fire on units, but never on cities.

Comment: Do you have vision of the cities?

Comment: It worked for me in a BNW game I finished last month.

Comment: @Ullallulloo, yes, I have vision of the cities.